# why does this C code outputs 1

Tags: c, computation

Is there any reason why:

```
void function_foo(){
    int k[8];
    function_math(k, 8);
}

void function_math(int *k, int i){
    printf("value: %d", k[i]);
}
```

The main execute `function_foo()`;

The output will be 1? There's no initialization for elements of matrix k.
Maybe something with the length of int in memory?

I am new to C concepts, the pointers and everything.

Comment: I edited. The main executes function_foo().

Comment: @DavidGrayson Eh? The call of function_math is in function_foo.

Comment: @DavidGrayson You should not engage in pointless pedantry. There are four answers here and they all got it right. Both the title and the text refer to "output" and there is one output statement. No guessing is necessary. "make it clearer" -- it was already plenty clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is *undefined behaviour* to evaluate `k[8]`, since `k` only has 8 elements, not 9.

There is little point arguing about the consequences of undefined behaviour. Anything could happen. Your program is not well-formed.

(Note that it would even be undefined behaviour to evaluate `k[0]`, ..., `k[7]`, since they are *unini­tia­lized*. You have to write to them first, or initialize the array, such as `int k[8] = { 1, 2 };`.)

Comment: If its an undefined behavior, why does the output is always 1? I mean, even if I rebuild and execute 10 times, my output still is 1 and not a random number..

Comment: @Pier-alexandreBouchard Undefined can be mean **anything** - including it always returning 1.

Comment: @Pier-alexandreBouchard: The behaviour "anything can happen" includes "always returns 1". It could also always delete a file from your photo collection, or always order one pizza.

Comment: Ok, I see now what does Undefined mean! Thank you guys!

Comment: hehe @KerrekSB This makes me smile :) But no panic, the operating system (linux, windows etc.) will check if you try to call an adress out of the memory space of your program and then shut down the lights of your program if you try to "order a pizza"

Comment: @JanKoester: That's not true in my own *AggressivelyNegligentOS*, for which I've just finished an optimizing, self-heuristifying C++ compiler. I'm hoping to get NASA to commission it for the next Mars lander, because it runs on really weak hardware... in 3D. Anyway, after a bug last week I've got a fridge full of spare pizzas.

Comment: awesome :) I need such an OS!

Comment: My nonconforming implementation can blow up the universe even if you give it valid code. This "anything can happen" stuff is dumb and misconstrues the meaning (and, as a former member of X3J11, I will note the intent) of the language in the C standard.

Comment: @JimBalter: Yeah, that's true... but a compiler is certainly allowed to make assumptions according to the standard and apply radical transformations to your code based on those assumptions, so I prefer to give a slightly too broad warning that a to narrow one. The correct advice should probably start with the words, "The compiler is allowed to assume that ...".

Comment: The C standard is a definition; it specifies what a conforming implementation of the C language is, and what a conforming C program is ... that's all. What various implementations can, or are allowed, to do is constrained by many practical factors aside from the C standard ... especially considering that all implementations have bugs that make them non-conforming.

Answer (score 2):

This is the value which is at the memory position after the last element of your declared array.

If you run this code in a week again, it could be 42 or anything else which is stored at this time on this specific memory address. Also a segmentation fault could be possible in this case.

Comment: This is because the memory is not updated with any other value until now.

Comment: @Pier-alexandreBouchard Jan said it *could* be different, not that it would be. Please read the many answers that explain this to you.

Answer (score 0):

You are stepping out of the bounds of the array k.

To access the last element of k try using `function_math(k, 7)`

The array is also not initialized so the values inside will be undefined.

Comment: Even *reading* from an uninitialized variable is undefined behaviour. That's a lot worse than reading undefined values.